# Python: Error con PyInstaller, no puedo instalarlo

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Me encuentro con este error al querer instalar pyinstaller. Al ejecutar la sentencia en la terminal de windows sucede lo mismo. Alguien sabe que podria hacer?

[image: error primera parte]

[image: error segunda parte]

Comment: Lo solucione con lo siguiente:

Comment: En cmd 
1. pip install wheel -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Y cuando se completo 
2. pip install Pyinstaller -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple